# Strange thing appears in Network locations - is it virus?

Tags: network, windows

Sometime, I see this "Living Room 1_5146 (HiMediaServer)" in Network locations, sometimes, I don't. Is this virus? Is it trying to spy me? What should I do?

I'm using Windows 8.1 - 64 bit.

[image]

Comment: There are no information known about your network. It is even unknown if your are connecting to the same network all the time. But it looks like there is some media server in the network or at least some device claiming to be one. If this is intended or not is unknown to us.

Comment: If that's a wireless connection it may be losing signal and sometimes dropping, or if not, the PC may enter stand-by. Check these. Provide more details about your network.

Comment: I'm connecting to a LAN (I don't use wireless, I connect the PC with the internet model through a cable). Now that "Living Room" is gone. That's what I'm afraid, it keeps appearing (rarely appearing) and disappearing. Could it be this is the device of someone who secretly uses my LAN?

Comment: do any of these things look familiar? http://www.himediatech.com/productList.htm

Comment: @schroeder : Oh, so that's a tv thing, that could be my cousin. Thanks.

Comment: All I did was google "HiMediaServer" ...

Comment: my bad, sorry, I google Living Room 1_5146 so I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself these questions:

- How many people share or have access to your wifi/router?
- Are any of these users including you, connecting some device that is reporting to be a media server?
- Try disconnecting or reconnecting devices around the area to identify what device it is.

If all else fails, and you are the routers owner/admin, try logging in to your routers settings (using the IP address of the default gateway using ipconfig), and it may show you a list of connected devices, check if you can identify them all. Also windows may tell you the IP address of the media server if you right-click it.

If you still cannot tell what it is, a last resort would be to change the wifi password. That device and all others, won't show up anymore until that device enters the correct credentials to re-connect.